# Отсутствует перевод "другой" причины закрытия вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, закрытие-вопросов

При добавлении собственной причины закрытия появляется новый пункт в меню. Он не локализован на RuSO

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного подправил вариант, предложенный MSDN.WhiteKnight, [итоговый](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14458):

> Другая причина (предложено другим участником)